# Why do I get a TypeError only when I use the input() method?

Tags: python, typeerror

I am working on two functions in a tic tac toe game. The "board" is a list, and the user uses the numpad to place his or her marker. The number is an index of the "board" list.

The first function - checks if a space on the board is available to play
and returns a boolean (if space is available, return True).

The second function - takes input from the user on where they place their marker, then uses the first function to check if it's a free position

```
board = ['#','X','O','X',' ','X','O','X','O','X']

def space_check(board, position):

     return board[position] == ' '
```

I test it -

```
space_check(board, 4)

>True


def player_choice(board):

     position = input("Player's next move")

     if space_check(board, position) == True:

          return position
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I am new and apologize if this is a mess. I very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Try `position = int(input("Player's next move"))`.  Currently, the input value is a `str`, but your function needs an `int` I guess.

Comment: A little tip: as you already found out that the problem is with the `input`'s result, all is left to do is google *python input* which will get you to the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) where it states: *The function then reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that*

Answer (score 2):

The `input()` function in python returns the user input as a `str` by default.

Because this is a string - you are unable to access the list - hence the `TypeError`

this can be solved by simply casting the `input()` statement as a `int` as so:

```
position = int(input("Player's next move"))
```

Now if you try this, it should work as expected!

:)

Answer (score 0):

The default return value of input is type str.

Change

```
position = input("Player's next move")
```

to

```
position = int(input("Player's next move"))
```